# Mocha beforeEach in one suite is being run in another suite

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have two test suites (I am using mocha's TDD UI, which uses `suite()`, test() rather than `describe()` and `it()`):

```
suite('first suite'), function(){
    ....
})


suite('second suite', function(){

    beforeEach(function(done){
        console.log('I SHOULD NOT BE RUN')
        this.timeout(5 * 1000);
        deleteTestAccount(ordering, function(err){
            done(err)
        })
    })

    ... 

}()
```

Running `mocha -g 'first suite` only runs tests from the first suite, but runs the beforeEach, printing `I SHOULD NOT BE RUN` on the console.

How can I make the `beforeEach()` only run in the suite it is contained within?

**Note**: I can workaround the issue with:

```
beforeEach(function(done){
    this.timeout(5 * 1000);
    if ( this.currentTest.fullTitle().includes('second suite') ) {
        deleteTestAccount(ordering, function(err){
            done(err)
        })
    } else {
        done(null)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `beforeEach` is not part of the TDD UI, but the BDD UI. The corresponding function for the TDD UI is `setup`. So try replacing `beforeEach` with `setup` and everything should work as you expect :).

Comment: Thanks! It's somewhat [subtle in the docs](http://mochajs.org/) - particularly since `beforeEach()` isn't as vague as other BDD style methods. The full set of differences: `before()` becomes `suiteSetup()`, `after()` becomes `suiteTeardown()`, `beforeEach()` becomes`setup()`, and `afterEach()` becomes `teardown()`.